# how do I update my state from an API call side Effect in React native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I have a piece of code that gets Metadata of a list of files from Firebase storage using the useEffect hook. I however, struggle to update my state within this useEffect. I have used the async/await pattern to mitigate the asynchronous nature of setState without much success.

My snippet in pseudocode:

```
const [someData,setSomeData]=useState([])
const dataArray=[]

useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(()=>{
        async function getData(){
            const result=await listAll(storageRef);
            await result.items.map(async (itemRef)=>{
                const Metadata=await getMetadata(itemRef);
                await dataArray.push({'name':Metadata.name})
                await console.log(dataArray) //shows the array being populated on each iteration
            })
            await setSomeData(dataArray);
            await console.log(someData) // I'm expecting it to print an updated state, prints an empty array instead
            }
            getData()
        },[])
    )
```

I also cannot seem to access the state in the return part of my code:

```
return(
    {someData.map(({item})=>{
        return(
            <View><Text>{item.name}</Text><View>)})
```

outputs nothing as far as I can tell.

What am I missing in my approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataArray` is  being re-initialized to `[]` every render, and then you are setting `someData` to `dataArray`, effectively setting `someData` to an empty array. I think if you wrap your async map in a Promise.all then you can have dataArray scoped to your `getData` function:

```js
const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
  async function getData() {
    const result = await listAll(storageRef);
    const dataArray = await Promise.all(
      result.items.map(async (itemRef) => {
        const Metadata = await getMetadata(itemRef);
        console.log(Metadata);
        return { name: Metadata.name };
      })
    );
    console.log("dataArray:\n", dataArray);
    setSomeData(dataArray);
    // even if you await setSomeData, someData wont be the the updated value. 
    /*  If you want to see someData changes do
      useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(someData)
      },[someData])
    */
  }
  getData();
}, []);
useFocusEffect(fetchData);
```

Answer (score 0):

- setSomeData() does not return a promise, thus cannot be awaited.
- dataArray needs to be scoped inside getData()
- getData closes around someData, so it will never get the updated value
  as that function call is referring to the previous value
- it might be easier to use a [react native compatible async data library](https://resthooks.io/)